# Position space and momentum space / time domain and frequency domain

Tags: momentum, fourier-transform, probability

Are these four concepts somehow connected or different?
I'd like to know in which case we consider one group and in which the other. For example we can talk about the wave function in position space, and from here we find the probability that an object is at a certain position. We can do the same in the momentum space. This is the only example I know. But i'd like go more in depth

Comment: Could you explain further what exactly your question is?

Comment: I simply want to know how are these concepts related to each other, and how are they different from each other?

Comment: But what concepts exactly? You just named Fourier transformation, as far as I can see.

Comment: All 4 of the concepts: Position space, momentum space, time domain ,frequency domain